# Max-Heap implementation: How to make first 3 nodes always the highest?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, heap

So I've been trying to implement the Max Heap. The use I want to give to it is that, at any one time, I want the first 3 elements of the heap (that is, the root and its two children) to always be the highest in the whole heap.

I thought the heap property would guarantee this, but not a single implementation example I have come across has been able to solve the fact that sometimes, there are elements in one level of the heap that are lower than an element in a higher level.
This is the implementation I've been using, basically by using examples I have found on the internet as reference:

```
let createHeap = function(){
  return {
    arr:[],
    size: 0,
    getParent: function(i) { return Math.floor((i-1)/2) },
    getLeft: function(i) { return (2*i + 1) },
    getRight: function(i) { return (2*i + 2) },
    insert: function(val){
      let i = this.size
      this.size++
      this.arr[i] = val;
      if(i!=0){
        for(let j = this.getParent(i);j>=0;j--){
          this.heapify(j)
        } 
      }
    },
    heapify: function(i){
      let largest = i;
      let leftIndex = this.getLeft(i)
      let rightIndex = this.getRight(i)
      if (leftIndex < this.size && this.arr[leftIndex] > this.arr[largest])
        largest = leftIndex
      if (rightIndex < this.size && this.arr[rightIndex] > this.arr[largest])
        largest = rightIndex;

      if (largest != i) {
        let temp = this.arr[largest];
        this.arr[largest] = this.arr[i]
        this.arr[i] = temp

        this.heapify(largest);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, the problem is, when I insert the following values in this order: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`
The result I get for the heap is:

```
5
|\
4 2
|\
1 3
```

This is clear when you read what the code does, but doesn't seem to conserve heap property as far as I got to understand what heap property means. The code is missing something to get to do what I want it to do, but I don't want to implement changes that would increase the complexity too badly, so I wanted to ask:

1. **Does anyone know if the implementation is wrong or if it was never meant to do what I want it to do? (first 3 elements of the heap are always the highest in the whole heap)**
2. **What would be the best way of implementing this without increasing the complexity too much?**

Comment: For a max heap, the heap property says: for any given node C, if P is a parent node of C, then the key (the value) of P is greater than or equal to the key of C. That does not imply that the top 3 values will be the root and its 2 immediate children ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure))).

Comment: Ok, so this clears the confusion I had regarding heap property. Thanks you my friend.

Comment: Can this question be closed? Or is there still a question here?

Comment: Yes, it can be closed as the main question has been answered.